# Mapping API response to another client DTO

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, jackson-databind

**[solved]
update: I was using lombok for getter/setters, and forgot to add @Data annotation on that class. Now fixed**.
I am calling `endpoint` of a `REST controller` from where my `Response` class has entity like this:

```
public class Response{
   private Long userId;
   private Long anotherId;
   private Collection<UserInfo> userInfo;
   private List<Map<String, List<AnotherDto>>> anotherDto;
 //setters and getters
};
```

Here,

```
public class UserInfo implements MyInterface{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  //and  @override methods
  //setters and getters
}
```

Now, In my client app, 
The `DTO` I am mapping to the `API` call response is same like I have described above, except, my `UserInfo`  class does n't implement any `interface` in client side.
When I make `API` call, from service side, I have checked that I got all the data as expected, but in client side, I get all except the `userInfo` for which `UserInfo` class doesn't implement the interface as I did on service side.
What is the issue here?
 **Any help please.**

Comment: Why not reuse the model  ? Duplication costs and generate issues.

Comment: @davidxxx, sorry, I didn't understand you clearly. Rest service and client are two different project and the interface I implemented here only needed on service side, not on the client project, that's why I have not used and generated here. Did you mean on this point?